# New Line on a web page- Java servlet

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am new to learning Java Servlet. I am trying to pass parameters through POST query(Apache Tomcat v8.0) using a simple html form that generates two input fields 'UserName' and 'FullName'.
The code is running perfectly however; I want 'UserName' and 'FullName' to display on separate new line and I cannot do it by using "/n" inside println() function.
Here is my POST query code.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
    String User_name = request.getParameter("UserName");
    String Full_name = request.getParameter("FullName");
    out.println("\nHello from POST method!");
    out.println("\nYour UserName is: " +User_name);
    out.println("\nYour FullName is: " +Full_name);
}
```

Comment: use tags of ``HTML`` ito get a new line in ```print``` statement as well No need to write ```println``` use ```print``` only it also works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\n` is newline for text. View source in browser, and you'll see the `\n` is giving you a newline in the HTML source.  The problem is, browsers don't display that `\n` as a newline in the rendered HTML.  That's because to make a newline in HTML you use either `<br />` for linebreak, or wrap your line into a paragraph beginning with `<p>` and ending with `</p>`.  If you're going to be doing JSP/Servlet development, you need to learn the basics of HTML.

So:

```
 out.println("<p>Hello from POST method!</p>"); 
 out.println("<p>Your UserName is: " + User_name + "</p>");
```

or

```
 out.println("Hello from POST method!"); 
 out.println("<br />Your UserName is: " + User_name);
```

Its also not recommended to print HTML directly in a servlet like this.  You should rather set a request attribute and forward to a JSP that acts as a view.  This is explained well in the [Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Just a hint for the future: After a post which has changed something on the server (saved to db or whatever) you will want to do a server-side redirect to prevent double posting.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch!